# Highchart pie - datalabel cannot be selected when setting useHTML=true

Tags: highcharts

when i set useHTML=true on pie datalabels the labels are not respond to mouse hover and not show tooltip

http://jsfiddle.net/wh4mw0o7/

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {},
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    useHTML:true, // <- THE PROBLEM !!!!!
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            data: [
                ['AAA', 10],
                ['BBB', 20],
                ['CCC', 15]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

do some one know how to fix it ?
i use html in the labels(different sizing and colors so i must use html as label).

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question? because tool-tip is working fine i think.

Comment: tooltip working well.. which HTML you want in labels??

Comment: Do you mean select by mouse click and move (like default text selection on the website) or something different? For me tooltip also works.

Comment: what i mean is:  if you REMOVE the useHTML:true ( set it false) and move ur mouse over the labels only, without entering the pie slices, it work good, the tooltip show correctly. but if you set the useHTML:true, and try to move the mouse ONLY on label, without enter in the pie, it not shown.

Answer (score 2):

See the http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting
and paragraph "The downsides are that it will always be laid out on top of all other SVG content, and that it is not rendered the same way in exported charts." It means that HTML elements are below SVG, which keeps events.

Related topic: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2158

EDIT:

```
 $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (i, d) {

        $('.highcharts-data-labels div span').eq(i).mouseover(function (e) {
            chart.tooltip.refresh(d);
        });
    });
```

Workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/wh4mw0o7/6/

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you can call the covering of each part of your pie chart.

```
dataLabels: {
    useHTML:true,            // Make our labels HTML
    formatter: function() {  // Wrap the text of each label with a span tag  

        // Id of the span is equal to 'label-<Name of your label>'
        return "<span id='label-" + this.point.name+ "'>" + 
        this.point.name + // And draw the label itself inside the span
        "</span>";
    }
}
```

Below the your chart options write event handlers:

```
// On the hover event of each label we can manually call the hover of 
// each segment of your pie chart
$('#label-AAA').hover(
    // When the mouse pointer enters the label, make it hovered and show its tooltip
    function() { 
        // data[0] - AAA segment of the chart
        mychart.series[0].data[0].setState('hover'); 
        // Refresh the tooltip of this segment
        mychart.tooltip.refresh(mychart.series[0].points[0]);  
    },        
    function() {    // When the mouse pointer leaves the label
       mychart.tooltip.hide();
});
```

For each label the code is same. The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to know all labels names in advance. Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wh4mw0o7/4/